# Unity 2.0: how to resolve constructor dependencies

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have an **IRequestManager** class that resolves to the **RequestManager** class, but I am getting System.IO.FileLoadException was unhandled by user code Message=The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

```
public class RequestManager : IRequestManager
{
    private IRepository<Request> _requestRepository;
    public RequestManager(IRepository<Request> requestRepository)
    {
        _requestRepository = requestRepository;
    }
    // ...
}
```

I am having trouble registering IRequestManager in my web.config; do I need to create explicitly register IRepository in the web.config?

Here is my web.config

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="PerOperationContext" type="UnityWcfExtensions.UnityOperationContextLifetimeManager, UnityWcfExtensions" />
    <container>
      <register type="MRF.Repository.IDbContext, MRF.Repository" mapTo="MRF.Repository.EntityFrameworkCodeFirst.MRFDbContext, MRF.Repository.EntityFrameworkCodeFirst">
        <lifetime type="PerOperationContext" />
        <constructor>
          <param name="nameOrConnectionString" value="MRFContext" type="string" />
        </constructor>
      </register>

      <register type="MRF.Repository.IUnitOfWorkFactory, MRF.Repository" mapTo="MRF.Repository.EntityFrameworkCodeFirst.MRFDbContext, MRF.Repository.EntityFrameworkCodeFirst">
        <lifetime type="PerOperationContext" />
        <constructor>
          <param name="nameOrConnectionString" value="MRFContext" type="string" />
        </constructor>
      </register>

      <register type="MRF.Repository.IRepository`1, MRF.Repository" mapTo="MRF.Repository.EntityFrameworkCodeFirst.GenericRepository`1, MRF.Repository.EntityFrameworkCodeFirst" />
      <register type="MRF.Business.Interfaces.IRequestManager, MRF.Business.Interfaces" mapTo="MRF.Business.RequestManager, MRF.Business">
        <constructor>
          <param name="requestRepository" type="MRF.Repository.IRepository`1[[MRF.Entities.Request, MRF.Entities]]">
            <dependency />
          </param>
        </constructor>

      </register>
      <register type="MRF.Mapping.IMapper`2[[MRF.Entities.Region, MRF.Entities],[MRF.Service.DataContract.Region, MRF.Service.DataContract]], MRF.Mapping" mapTo="MRF.Mapping.AutoMapper.RegionMapper, MRF.Mapping.AutoMapper" />
      <register type="MRF.Mapping.IMapper`2[[MRF.Entities.User, MRF.Entities],[MRF.Service.DataContract.User, MRF.Service.DataContract]], MRF.Mapping" mapTo="MRF.Mapping.AutoMapper.UserMapper, MRF.Mapping.AutoMapper" />
      <register type="MRF.Mapping.IMapper`2[[MRF.Entities.UserPreference, MRF.Entities],[MRF.Service.DataContract.UserPreference, MRF.Service.DataContract]], MRF.Mapping" mapTo="MRF.Mapping.AutoMapper.UserPreferenceMapper, MRF.Mapping.AutoMapper" />
      <register type="MRF.Mapping.IMapper`2[[MRF.Entities.Status, MRF.Entities],[MRF.Service.DataContract.Status, MRF.Service.DataContract]], MRF.Mapping" mapTo="MRF.Mapping.AutoMapper.StatusMapper, MRF.Mapping.AutoMapper" />
      <register type="MRF.Mapping.IMapper`2[[MRF.Entities.Request, MRF.Entities],[MRF.Service.DataContract.Request, MRF.Service.DataContract]], MRF.Mapping" mapTo="MRF.Mapping.AutoMapper.RequestMapper, MRF.Mapping.AutoMapper" />
      <register type="MRF.Mapping.IMapper`2[[MRF.Entities.Series, MRF.Entities],[MRF.Service.DataContract.Series, MRF.Service.DataContract]], MRF.Mapping" mapTo="MRF.Mapping.AutoMapper.SeriesMapper, MRF.Mapping.AutoMapper" />
    </container>
  </unity>
```

My current work around is to manually create a new instance of RequestManager in my WCF service and pass in the resolved constructor parameters as shown below:

```
public DC.Request GetRequest(int requestId)
{
    var requestRepository = this.Container.Resolve<IRepository<BE.Request>>();
    var requestManager = new RequestManager(requestRepository);
    var request = requestManager.GetRequest(requestId);
    var userMapper = this.Container.Resolve<IMapper<BE.User, DC.User>>();
    var seriesMapper = this.Container.Resolve<IMapper<BE.Series, DC.Series>>();
    var statusMappger = this.Container.Resolve<IMapper<BE.Status, DC.Status>>();
    var mapper = this.Container.Resolve<IMapper<BE.Request, DC.Request>>();
    return mapper.Map(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a silly mistake...
In the register node in the web.config for MRF.Interfaces.IRequestManager, I was using the namespace instead of the project name!

After I corrected the web.config, I didn't have to add any extra configuration and the following code worked just fine!

```
public DC.Request GetRequest(int requestId)
{
    var requestManager = this.Container.Resolve<IRequestManager>();
    var request = requestManager.GetRequest(requestId);
    var userMapper = this.Container.Resolve<IMapper<BE.User, DC.User>>();
    var seriesMapper = this.Container.Resolve<IMapper<BE.Series, DC.Series>>();
    var statusMappger = this.Container.Resolve<IMapper<BE.Status, DC.Status>>();
    var mapper = this.Container.Resolve<IMapper<BE.Request, DC.Request>>();
    return mapper.Map(request);
}
```

So, instead of

```
<register type="MRF.Business.Interfaces.IRequestManager, MRF.Business.Interfaces" mapTo="MRF.Business.RequestManager, MRF.Business" />
```

I had to to do the following:

```
<register type="MRF.Business.Interfaces.IRequestManager, MRF.Business" mapTo="MRF.Business.RequestManager, MRF.Business" />
```

Comment: Just a clarification - the Type attribute in your example is looking for the fully qualified type name and the _assembly name_, not the project name.  By default the project name will be used as the assembly name, but it is important to differentiate because they don't have to be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I am not a big fan of Unity personally, but I have to use it at work. If I had a choice, I would use Ninject.